# Get random element using XPath

Tags: xml, xpath, random, for-xml-path

I need to get a random element of a specific result set. I have a working XPath expression and need the same thing in the other one. This is what i have right now:

The working one:

```
ad/item[[eval:('Math.floor(Math.random()*7)+1')]]
```

and this is the one I need. It needs also the random in but with the filter on recommended:

```
query/results/json/feed/entry[contains(gsx_type/_t,'recommended')]
```

I know that if i just want a number I can put it like this:

```
query/results/json/feed/entry[contains(gsx_type/_t,'recommended')][3]
```

or

```
query/results/json/feed/entry[(contains(gsx_type/_t,'recommended')) AND (item = 3) ]
```

But this is not what I need. I have 12 pictures that are recommended so maybe if someone knows what to write to make this work that would be really great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly what you want to achieve, you can simply combine both:

```
query/results/json/feed/entry[contains(gsx_type/_t,'recommended')][eval:('Math.floor(Math.random()*7)+1')]
```

However, this `eval:()` function looks very strange to me, you might also be able to use a random module provided by your processor or call a functions differently. Also, if you have 12 pictures you might want to change the `7` to `12`.

Comment: Thank you very much i though of that indeed your answer confirmed it.